# "Overwrite users' personal custom app customizations" is not changeable

Tags: managed-package, app-development, app

I installed my managed package beta in a sandbox, and realized that the tabs I had set in the developer org were not respected.

I went to Create -> Apps in the developer org, and noticed that for my application the "Overwrite users' personal custom app customizations" was unchecked.  I checked and saved without error, but when I loaded the page again the checkbox was unchecked.

As far as I know this is the only way to overwrite visible tabs and tab order in the target org, so I would like to know why my choice does not seem to be respected.

I had a look at the application metadata but could not see any boolean flag I could set.

Comment: I'm not certain you could do that when installing a managed package because of the security/admin level permissions required. Further, what about the users that might not be using your managed packed?(I realize that may not apply) I think most admins would be really PO'd if installing a package changed everyone's custom tab settings. Just having the defaults for your app would seem to me to be what's appropriate. Let admins lock it down afterward if you really believe its necessary.

Comment: But I only want to set my tabs for my own app, not any other apps.  Currently the tabs shown is an old version of the application, which makes me think it was possible at some point :S  What do you mean by 'having the defaults for your app'?  I have available tabs and moved the ones I want visible to selected tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have no problem setting the tabs for your own app, but changing the custom tab settings for User Profiles is a global setting for **all** apps, not just your own! Take a look at Chapter 7 of [Force.com Fundamentals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf) where those settings are covered in detail. Tab settings can be controlled through both User Profiles and through Permission Sets.

For your app, if you have custom profiles, you should see something like this:

> In the Custom App Settings area, make the Recruiting app visible to
>   users assigned to the Recruiter profile, as shown in the following
>   screenshot.
>
> [image]
>
> Figure 49: Profile Custom App Settings Area
>
> Tip: You can also give this profile access to any of the other available apps as well.
>   Every profile needs to have at least one visible app.

However, in an existing org where the profiles already exist, you'll see something that looks more like the image below:

> The Overwrite users' personal tab customizations setting appears if you have
>   an organization that's currently in use and you want to make sure your existing users are viewing
>   the tabs that you've selected. You don't need to select this for our app because we're defining
>   a brand-new profile and no one has personalized his or her tab visibility settings yet. However,
>   if you do want to select this option at some point in the future, just make sure you're not going
>   to annoy your users by deleting all of their customizations!

[image]

Tab visibility by tab/object can also be controlled through permission sets as shown in the image below:

[image]

If your App includes permission sets, that could be why your tabs aren't behaving as expected. Any changes to the permission sets would need to be implemented with the new version of your app as well.

Answer (score 1):

The "Overwrite User's Personal Tabs" customization isn't a metadata setting.  For each app user's can alter the default list of tabs shown by removing those that are shown by default (Default On) and showing those that are excluded (Default Off).  However, sometimes an administrator might want to force a change to the tabs shown by clearing all user's tab customizations which can be accomplished by checking the box.  Since just applies to a particular save the box will always show up as unchecked and can't be found in any metadata.